# Diplomacy solo practice site

Tags: diplomacy

Are there any sites online that will allow me to practice
a) submitting orders accurately.
b) allow me to run through attack scenarios online, to see how they end up going?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the online Diplomacy playing site [Backstabbr](http://backstabbr.com) has a "sandbox" feature that does that.

It is perfect to go through attack scenarios and see how they end up.

For practicing submitting orders, you enter orders by clicking on the map, and see how they would be written by hand. You don't submit textual orders. I guess you could write them down by hand first, and see whether the generated order is the same.

Comment: Perfect - that's EXACTLY what I was looking for. :)